# Need to calculate replication lag across multiple region in Cassandra Cluster

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to setup a Datastax Cassandra Cluster spanning across two different regions in AWS.The data is getting replicated to nodes in secondary region but I want to calculate the replication lag of the data which is getting replicated from primary to secondary region. Tried to make use of WRITETIME function but seems its recorded when the write happens and then the value gets replicated as it is to other nodes. Is there any other way that we can use to find the replication lag of data being copied from nodes on one region to nodes in another region? The version in use is DSE 6.8.0.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to calculate network latency between two regions. That is the main thing in inter DC communication otherwise if you have similar resources in both DC node latency should be same. For network latency in AWS you can use https://www.cloudping.info/ or https://cloudpingtest.com/aws.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tried using sjk with nodetool to print the node latency data.